# Collect and parse JSON from MongoLab

Tags: ios, json, swift, rest, mlab

I'm working with an app that will be using MongoLab as a host for mongodb. I found this tutorial: [Devdactic](http://devdactic.com/rest-api-parse-json-swift/), and I easily made it work locally on my own computer. The problem is that instead of the api provided in that tutorial, I want to use my own MongoLab API. My API-path looks like this:

https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/DBName/collections/CollName?apiKey=MyAPIKey

Which returns this JSON:

```
[ { "_id" : { 
        "$oid" : "55f853a2e4b0d8eab7e4a058"
    } , 
    "coordinate" : { 
        "latitude" : "123" , 
        "longitude" : "456"
    }
} ]
```

Yeah I know, it's not an very advanced JSON, it's just to see if it works at all.

My code is written in Swift, and from the tutorial I've created a RestAPIManager class that looks like this:

```
typealias ServiceResponse = (JSON, NSError?) -> Void

class RestApiManager: NSObject {
static let sharedInstance = RestApiManager()
let baseURL = "https://api.mongolab.com/api/1/databases/DBName/collections/CollName?apiKey=MyAPIKey"

func getCoordinate(onCompletion: (JSON) -> Void) {
    let route = baseURL
    makeHTTPGetRequest(route, onCompletion: { json, err in
        onCompletion(json as JSON)
    })
}

func makeHTTPGetRequest(path: String, onCompletion: ServiceResponse) {
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: path)!)

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        let json:JSON = JSON(data: data)
        onCompletion(json, error)
    })
    task.resume()
  }
}
```

Then I try to "get" the response from this API in a ViewController, on a button-click like this:

```
@IBAction func addBuoyButtonClick(sender: AnyObject) {

    getDataFromAPI()

}

func getDataFromAPI(){     
    RestApiManager.sharedInstance.getCoordinate { json in
        let results = json["coordinate"]
        for (index: String, subJson: JSON) in results {
            let latitude: AnyObject = subJson["latitude"].object

            let alert = UIAlertView()
            alert.title = "Latitude: "
            alert.message = "Lat: " + latitude.string as String
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
            alert.show()

        }
    }
}
```

Just to see if it works, I try to alert the response in an alert-view. The result is nothing! The alert-view doesn't even show.

Sorry for long post, but I thought it would be better with some actual code rather than wild guessing! :P

Comment: Sorry for spamming, but isn't there anyone with experience on the topic?